# convert unicode of form "\uxxxxxx" to string or text

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-escapes

I'm writing an python script which will extract the url of facebook video. But in the source of the video page, i see some characters of form \uxxxxxx in the url.

for instance url is in this form

```
https\u00253A\u00255C\u00252F\u00255C\u00252Ffbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net\u00255C\u00252Fhvideo-ak-prn2\u00255C\u00252Fv\u00255C\u00252F753002_318048581647953_53890_n.mp4\u00253Foh\u00253D64e3e8ecf7e88f1da335d88949b2dc1f\u002526oe\u00253D52226D10\u002526__gda__\u00253D1377987338_9e37fb163a1d37d4b06ab7cff668f7dc\u002522\u00252C\u002522
```

\u00253A is colon (:), but how do i convert it.

When i did like

```
>>> x.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii','ignore')
```

i get

```
'https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Ffbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net%5C%2Fhvideo-ak-prn2%5C%2Fv%5C%2F753002_318048581647953_53890_n.mp4%3Foh%3D64e3e8ecf7e88f1da335d88949b2dc1f%26oe%3D52226D10%26__gda__%3D1377987338_9e37fb163a1d37d4b06ab7cff668f7dc%22%2C%22
```

I want exact url not percentage.

I searched a lot but couldn't find any help.

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Is there any way if I pass the whole source of facebook page and then convert all such complex unicode character to simple one.

Comment: That's a weird double-escaped string.

Comment: @mechanical not only url, but most of it is present in javascript.For instance check source of https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10102527792694996 . Press CTRL+F and look for ".mp4"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import urllib
>>> s = b'https\u00253A\u00255C\u00252F\u00255C\u00252Ffbcdn-video'
>>> print urllib.unquote_plus(s.decode('unicode_escape'))
https:\/\/fbcdn-video
```

It seems that your string is backslashed.

```
>>> import re
>>> import urllib
>>> s = b'https\u00253A\u00255C\u00252F\u00255C\u00252Ffbcdn-video'
>>> re.sub(r'\\(.)', r'\1', urllib.unquote_plus(s.decode('unicode_escape')))
u'https://fbcdn-video'
```

Comment: yeah but i want to change it exact url which type in url bar

Comment: Is there method in any library in python in which I can pass the whole source and it convert it to normal string or text

Comment: @vaibhav1312 not sure I understand your question? Just put the whole source in a string variable and run the last line I gave in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @viktor. It converted all of them